# Using digital pin 11 for DMDCon and IR remote

Tags: arduino-uno, led, ir

I have a project where I would like to control a countdown clock using a remote with:

Arduino Uno R3 Development Board

Funduino Uno Protoshield Board

[Freetronics Dot Matrix Display Connector](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0045/8932/files/DMDCON_DMDConnector.pdf?100730)

[Arduino IR Reciever](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/IR-RemoteControl)

Both the DMDCon and the IR use digital pin 11. Can these two share the pin 11 or is there a workaround of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround would be to configure the https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote library referenced in your question to any available digital input.

Comment: Great Thanks For Your Help! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Kerl Not all pins might be supported, see the documentation about supported pins.